# Deriving the normal equation for linear regression

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, linear-regression

I have been looking at different derivations of the normal equation for linear regression. The derivation that I could  follow best (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_EH2abOp00) has some errors, unfortunately. So I tried to do the derivation myself without these errors. I am hung at a single step in the derivation. That step is the "something something" step. Everything seems to fit with the exception that I seem to need a $- 2 X^Ty$ but only have a $- y^TX - X^Ty$. Can you help me spot the error or tell me why the "something something" step is actually correct?

Here is my derivation:

Let $X$ be an $n \times p$ data matrix of $n$ items 'a $p$ features. Let $\hat{\beta}$ be the weight vector that minimizes the residual sum of squares (RSS) of $y - \hat{y}$, where $\hat{y} - X\hat{\beta}$. Hence, To find $\hat{\beta}$, find the minimum of RSS.

\begin{align*}
    \text{RSS} & =  (y - \hat{y})^T (y - \hat{y})\\
               & = (y - X\hat{\beta})^T (y - X\hat{\beta})\\
               & = (y^T - \hat{\beta}^TX^T) (y - X\hat{\beta})\\
               & = y^Ty - y^TX\hat{\beta} - \hat{\beta}^TX^Ty + \hat{\beta}^TX^TX\hat{\beta}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial ~ \text{RSS}}{\partial \hat{\beta}} & = \frac{\partial y^Ty - y^TX\hat{\beta} - \hat{\beta}^TX^Ty + \hat{\beta}^TX^TX\hat{\beta}}{\partial \hat{\beta}}\\
        & = \frac{\partial y^Ty}{\partial\hat{\beta}} - \frac{\partial \overbrace{y^TX\hat{\beta}}^{Ax}}{\partial\hat{\beta}} - \frac{\partial \overbrace{\hat{\beta}^TX^Ty}^{x^TA}}{\partial\hat{\beta}} + \frac{\partial \overbrace{\hat{\beta}^TX^TX\hat{\beta}}^{x^TAx}}{\partial \hat{\beta}} \\
        & \text{by these rules:} \frac{d~ Ax}{dx} = A, \frac{d~ x^TA}{dx} = A, \frac{d~ x^TAx}{dx} = 2Ax\\
        & = 0 - \underbrace{y^TX}_{A} - \underbrace{X^Ty}_{A} + \underbrace{2X^T X \hat{\beta}}_{2Ax} 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    0 & = \frac{\partial ~ \text{RSS}}{\partial \hat{\beta}}\\
        & = - y^TX - X^Ty + 2X^T X \hat{\beta}  \\
        & \text{something something}\\
        & = - 2 X^Ty + 2X^T X \hat{\beta}  \\
        \implies\\
        & X^Ty = X^T X \hat{\beta}  \\
        \implies\\
        &  ( X^T X)^{-1} X^Ty =  \hat{\beta} \\
\end{align*}

## Edit:

Ok, so after adjusting for a consistent layout as mentioned in the accepted answer, the derivation is this:

\begin{align*}
    \text{RSS} & =  (y - \hat{y})^T (y - \hat{y})\\
               & = (y - X\hat{\beta})^T (y - X\hat{\beta})\\
               & = (y^T - \hat{\beta}^TX^T) (y - X\hat{\beta})\\
               & = y^Ty - y^TX\hat{\beta} - \hat{\beta}^TX^Ty + \hat{\beta}^TX^TX\hat{\beta}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial ~ \text{RSS}}{\partial \hat{\beta}} & = \frac{\partial y^Ty - y^TX\hat{\beta} - \hat{\beta}^TX^Ty + \hat{\beta}^TX^TX\hat{\beta}}{\partial \hat{\beta}}\\
        & = \frac{\partial y^Ty}{\partial\hat{\beta}} - \frac{\partial \overbrace{y^TX\hat{\beta}}^{Ax}}{\partial\hat{\beta}} - \frac{\partial \overbrace{\hat{\beta}^TX^Ty}^{x^TA}}{\partial\hat{\beta}} + \frac{\partial \overbrace{\hat{\beta}^TX^TX\hat{\beta}}^{x^TAx}}{\partial \hat{\beta}} \\
        & \text{by these rules:} \frac{d~ Ax}{dx} = A, \frac{d~ x^TA}{dx} = A^T, \frac{d~ x^TAx}{dx} = 2x^TA\\
        & = 0 - \underbrace{y^TX}_{A} - \underbrace{(X^Ty)^T}_{A^T} + \underbrace{2 \hat{\beta}^T X^T X }_{2x^TA}\\
        & = 2 \hat{\beta}^T X^T X - 2 y^TX
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    0 & = \frac{\partial ~ \text{RSS}}{\partial \hat{\beta}}\\
        & = 2 \hat{\beta}^T X^T X - 2 y^TX\\
        \implies\\
        & Xy^T = \hat{\beta}^T X^T X  \\
        \implies\\
        & \hat{\beta}^T = Xy^T  (X^T X)^{-1}  \\
        \implies\\
        & \hat{\beta} = (X^T X)^{-1} X^Ty    \\
\end{align*}

Comment: My favorite way to compute the gradient of the least squares objective function $L(\beta) = \frac12 \| X \beta -y \|^2$ is using the chain rule. Note that $L(\beta) = g(h(\beta))$ where $h(\beta) =  X \beta - y$ and $g(u) = \frac12 \| u \|^2$. The derivatives of $g$ and $h$ are $h'(\beta) = X$ and $g'(u) = u^T$. By the chain rule, $L'(\beta) = g'(h(\beta)) h'(\beta) = (X \beta - y)^T X$. The gradient of $L$ is the column vector $\nabla L(\beta) = L'(\beta)^T = X^T (X \beta - y)$. Setting $\nabla L(\beta) = 0$ yields the normal equations $X^T(X \beta - y) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're following a [Denominator layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions) then the issue might be with your first derivative rule, which should have been:
$$
\frac{\partial Ax}{\partial x} = A^T
$$
(see [Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Vector-by-vector_identities))

This should turn your $y^TX$ into $X^Ty$ and you'd end up with
$$
0 = -2X^Ty + 2X^TX\hat{\beta} \implies (X^TX)^{-1} X^Ty = \hat{\beta}
$$

EDIT:
I've looked at the video and the author seems to be using the *Nominator layout*, in which case the second derivative rule should have been:
$$
\frac{\partial x^TA}{\partial x} = A^T
$$
which turns $X^Ty$ into $y^TX$ instead.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the different layouts!