# How do I simply this equation further, in order to get the parameter I'm looking for?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, machine-learning

I have a machine learning model. I want to find the critical point, at which the cost function converges. So I took it's derivative, set it equal to zero. I want to simplify it and find the optimal $w$.

This is what I've done so far.

The equation is: $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial w} = -\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i (y_i - x_i^T w) = 0$$

Solving step by step like this:

multiply both sides

$$\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i (y_i - x_i^T w) = 0 *  \frac{n}{2}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i x_i^T w= 0$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i x_i^T w$$

$w$ becomes a row vector to preserve the right orientation, so I transposed it:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n y_ix_i = w^T(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i x_i^T)$$

And this is where I stopped. How do I simplify it more, in order to get the $w$ ? Please I also need some explenations of the steps you provide, in order for me to understand and put the pieces together.

#### EDIT:

I multiplied both sides by the equation $(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i x_i^T)^{-1}$,
so we get $$(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i x_i^T)^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^n y_ix_i = w^T(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i x_i^T)(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i x_i^T)^{-1}$$

So now how do I get $w$? thanks!

Comment: after you multiplied by the inverse, those matrices on the RHS should disappear

Comment: Yes, the right side would only have $w^T$, and after that how do I find the final $w$ ?

Comment: Then you can take the transpose of both sides of the equation, since the transpose of $w^T$ is $w$.

Comment: @AlanChung And is it okay that I took out the $w$ from the $\sum$ and transposed it? I said that I took out the $w$ to presereve the right orientation, but I don't now how to explain it actually I just saw it some where, can you help me with it?

Comment: I would recommend maybe you just search it up. This equation is called the Normal Equation for Linear Regression. You can check out this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4177039/deriving-the-normal-equation-for-linear-regression